# How to choose ode solver in simulink for automobile applications

Tags: matlab, model, simulink, ode

Can anyone tell me how to choose the ODE solvers in order to design a automobile model? There are various ode solvers in simulink. Can I know the differences for each ode solver and for which type of applications these solvers should be used.

It will be of great help if I get some guidance regarding this.

Thank you in advance for the well wishers.

Answer (score 0):

See [Choose a Solver](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html) in the Simulink documentation. If you are using Simscape or other physical modelling tools, also check out [Setting Up Solvers for Physical Models](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ug/setting-up-solvers-for-physical-models.html) in the Simscape documentation.